# Error while using 2d Vectors in c++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

```
vector <vector <int>> frameVecs(4);
vector <int> t1 = getPeaks (vec1);
vector <int> t2 = getPeaks (vec2);
vector <int> t3 = getPeaks (vec3);
vector <int> t4 = getPeaks (vec4);

frameVecs[0].reserve(t1.size());
frameVecs[1].reserve(t2.size());
frameVecs[2].reserve(t3.size());
frameVecs[3].reserve(t4.size());

frameVecs.push_back (t1);
frameVecs.push_back (t2);
frameVecs.push_back (t3);
frameVecs.push_back (t4);
```

I always get `subscript out of range` error during the pushback part of the snippet.

Just two days back I was with this code that does the same thing:

```
vector <vector <int>> frameVecs;

frameVecs.push_back (getPeaks (vec1));
frameVecs.push_back (getPeaks (vec2));
frameVecs.push_back (getPeaks (vec3));
frameVecs.push_back (getPeaks (vec4));
```

And this was running just fine for the last 2 months .. and suddenly I started getting `subscript out of range` error in the pushback part and hence I had to change thsi particular part into the one above it, and still I am getting this error.

I mean, are `vectors` so uncertain in their behavior ?

PS: getPeaks() returns an `int` vector!

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem with the provided code but nothing bad happens. If the code in question hasn't changed when the problem first occured it might be a multithreading problem. What are you trying to accomplish with printing `endl` after every `push_back`?

Comment: please provide a [SSCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Afraid it's your understanding that is uncertain. Because of this you are making it more complicated that it needs to be.

Comment: You should post a callstack as well. Also check in your version control system exactly what changes you've made lately. If you're not using one, it's time to start.

Answer (score 4):

I think `push_back` doesn't do what you think it does.

```
vector <vector <int>> frameVecs(4);
```

Passing 4 to the vector on construction already creates 4 empty `int`-vectors. If you `push_back` the 4 vectors `t1`, `t2`, `t3` and `t4` you add another 4 vectors to `frameVecs`, so you actually have 8 entries in `frameVecs`. Maybe removing `(4)` and just writing:

```
vector <vector <int>> frameVecs;
```

will solve the problem.

If you now try to access `frameVecs[0][0]` for example (although not shown in your example) you get an error.

After the 4th `push_back` `frameVecs` looks like this:

```
frameVecs[0] // empty
frameVecs[1] // empty
frameVecs[2] // empty
frameVecs[3] // empty
frameVecs[4] // contains t1
frameVecs[5] // contains t2
frameVecs[6] // contains t3
frameVecs[7] // contains t4
```

Calling `reserve` is also unnecessary in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Excelcius's answer is good, but here's another way to do what I think you are trying to do.

```
vector <vector <int>> frameVecs(4);
frameVecs[0] = getPeaks (vec1);
frameVecs[1] = getPeaks (vec2);
frameVecs[2] = getPeaks (vec3);
frameVecs[3] = getPeaks (vec4);
```

The main thing here is that this code is *simpler* than your code. When simple things get as complicated as your code it's a pretty clear indication that something is wrong.

Main misunderstanding seems to be that *either* you set the size of a vector in the constructor *or* you dynamically increase the size using push_back, rarely do you want to do both.

Comment: I think both our answers are ok, but I still believe there's something missing in the example. Nowhere near the `push_back` does he access any of the vectors and the unnecessary `endl` outputs lead me to the assumption that he omitted something like `cout << frameVecs[0][0] << endl;` from the example.